# KMS is rejecting my license keys

Tags: licensing, kms

I'm trying to activate a Windows 7 Professional laptop, and I have a Windows Server 2008 on which I've activated KMS:

```
cscript slmgr.vbs /ipk {My_KMS_Key}
```

`My_KMS_Key` is the key from the licensing site listed next to "`Windows Server 2008 Std/Ent KMS B`"

The thing I can't find clearly explained is whether or not I should be adding Win 7 licenses to the KMS server in some way?

I have the following KMS keys available on the licensing site:

- Windows Vista - KMS
- Win 7 - KMS
- Windows Server 2008R2 Std/Ent KMS B
- Windows Server 2008 Std/Ent KMS B

I have the following MAK keys available on the licensing site:

- Windows Vista - MAK
- Win 7 - MAK
- Windows Server 2008R2 Std/Ent - MAK B
- Windows Server 2008 Std/Ent MAK B

Here's the current DLI:

```
cscript slmgr.vbs /dli
Name: Windows Server(R), ServerStandardV edition
Description: Windows Operating System - Windows Server(R), VOLUME_KMS_B channel
Partial Product Key: XXXXX
License Status: Licensed

Key Management Service is enabled on this machine
    Current count: 0
    Listening on Port: 1688
    DNS publishing enabled
    KMS priority: Normal

Key Management Service cumulative requests received from clients
    Total requests received: 0
    Failed requests received: 0
    Requests with License Status Unlicensed: 0
    Requests with License Status Licensed: 0
    Requests with License Status Initial grace period: 0
    Requests with License Status License expired or Hardware out of tolerance: 0

    Requests with License Status Non-genuine grace period: 0
    Requests with License Status Notification: 0
```

(Incidentally, I have installed KMS 1.2 using the Windows6.0-KB968912-v2-x64.msu download)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You REALLY need to read the documentation.

> The thing I can't find clearly
>   explained is whether or not I should
>   be adding Win 7 licenses to the KMS
>   server in some way?

Your key is a Windows Server 2008 Std/Ent KMS B key, which means it will activate everything that is livenced with a KMS B key. Check http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/existing-customers/product-activation-faq.aspx for an explnattion what is in there.

A MAK key is... for MAK (Multi Activation of clients). Technically you used a KMS Key, not a MAK Key.

Comment: That's fine, I used the KMS key that I think I'm supposed to. I amended my question to fix the typo - My_Mak_Key was actually supposed to be My_KMS_Key.  The thing is, how do I use the Win7 KMS key?  Will that server "KMS B" key not activate Win7 clients?

Comment: It will, the moment you have enough computers contacting the KMS. For clients that means 25 requests for activation before it starts activating them.

Comment: Aah, thanks.  So I assume that for the first 25, I use MAK's?  Also, is it correct that "total requests received" stays at zero until the 26th request?

Comment: Only if you dont have25 to start with. Servers / VM's also count. Total reusts received has NO indication. It is - common sense, as the name indicates - the number of requests RECEIVED. It does not say different machines, it does not say answered. If that does not count up - check firewall settings ;)